# Xamarin forms TabbedPage View Model called multiple time

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, tabbedpage

I have implemented Tabbedpage using ViewModel but my ViewModel constructor call 4 times because I create 4 tabs, I also used prism for ViewModel binding.

Below is a design file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms" 
            xmlns:material="clr-namespace:XF.Material.Forms.UI;assembly=XF.Material"
            xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
            xmlns:ffTransformations="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Transformations;assembly=FFImageLoading.Transformations" 
            prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
            xmlns:extended="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Extended;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Extended.InfiniteScrolling"
            xmlns:customcontrols="clr-namespace:QuranicQuizzes.CustomControls"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QuranicQuizzes.Views" NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True"
             x:Class="QuranicQuizzes.Views.DashboardPage">
      <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Dashboard" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="{StaticResource QuranFontBold}" FontSize="Medium" />
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
               <material:MaterialMenuButton x:Name="Menus" ButtonType="Text" Image="list" TintColor="White" BackgroundColor="Transparent" CornerRadius="24" Choices="{Binding Actions}"  MenuSelected="MaterialMenuButton_MenuSelected"  />
            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <local:HomeTabPage/>
        <local:QuizzesTabPage/>
        <local:LiveGameTabPage/>
        <local:AssignmentTabPage/>

</TabbedPage>
```

Below is my code

```
public partial class DashboardPage : TabbedPage
    {
        private DashboardPageViewModel vm;
        public DashboardPage()
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                vm = BindingContext as DashboardPageViewModel;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }
}
```

Below is my ViewModel

```
public class DashboardPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
 INavigationService _navigationService;
        IClientAPI _clientAPI;
        Dashboards dashboard;
   public DashboardPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IClientAPI clientAPI) : base(navigationService)
        {
            _navigationService = navigationService;
            _clientAPI = clientAPI;

            if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
            {
                var StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                var Enddate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                if (dashboard == null)
                {
                    dashboard = new Dashboards();
                    getDashboardData(StartDate, Enddate);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're trying to do. You want to initialise your vm instance so that you can access you vm from your view.

Instead of doing this:

```
vm = BindingContext as DashboardPageViewModel;
```

what we can do is change the type of the existing BindingContext property by doing this:

```
public partial class DashboardPage
{
     new DashboardPageViewModel BindingContext
     {
        get => (DashboardPageViewModel) base.BindingContext;
        set => base.BindingContext = value;
     }

     public DashboardPage()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
     }
}
```

now you can just access `BindingContext.DoSomething` because its type is now `DashboardPageViewModel`.

Now that's sorted out, your viewmodel should not be being called 4 times! Something is wrong here. Here is a checklist of things to do that may be causing the constructor being called 4 times as not a lot more info was provided.

- Try removing `<NavigationPage.TitleView>` segment.
- Make sure you are navigating to DashboardPage.
- Make sure that each individual TabbedPage has it's own viewmodel.
- Try removing `prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"`and manually adding the viewmodel to the TabbedPage.

Finally constructors should be able to run very fast and should **only** be used for assigning variables or instantiation or very quick operations. What you could maybe do is separate the code in your VM:

```
public class DashboardPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    IClientAPI _clientAPI;
    Dashboards dashboard;

    public DashboardPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IClientAPI clientAPI) : base(navigationService)
    {
        _clientAPI = clientAPI;
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
        {
            var StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            var Enddate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            if (dashboard == null)
            {
                dashboard = new Dashboards();
                getDashboardData(StartDate, Enddate);
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

and then in your view you could add this method:

```
protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
{
    base.OnBindingContextChanged();

     if(BindingContext == null)
     {
         return;
     }

     BindingContext.Init();
 }
```

I hope this really helps you.

**NB:** All this code was written on the fly and never compiled, there may be some errors.